# Help showing compactness of the support of a function in the Sobolev Space $W^{1,p}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, by Haim Brezis, in the proof of Theorem 8.12, it is needed to show that the support of a function is compact.

The function is $u_n(x):= (1/n)G(nu(x))$, where $G \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and verifies $G(t) \leq |t|$ and: $$ G(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 0 & if \ |t| \leq 1\\ 
 t & if \ |t| \geq 2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

And $u$ belongs to the Sobolev Space $W^{1,p}(I)$, where $I$ is a (possibly unbounded) interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Also, **$u=0$ on $\partial(I)$**. Recall that if $I$ is unbounded, then it verifies $$\lim_{x\in I, |x| \to \infty}{u(x)}=0 \quad \quad (1)$$.

What the proof says is:

> $supp(u_n) \subset \{x \in I \  | \ |u(x)| \geq 1/n \}$, so, **using the fact that $u=0$ on $\partial(I)$** and (1) then $supp(u_n)$ is compact.

And this is what I don't understand. Where is the marked in bold used? As far as I know, checking if a set is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ can be done by checking if it is closed (Which it is because the definition of the support) and bounded, which it is because it is a subset of a bounded set.

And the last fact is due to (1) if $I$ is unbounded and there is no assumption needed if $I$ is bounded. What am I missing?

Comment: You have something confused - the $u_n$ in your question obvious does not have compact support.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, Could you explain me why? I don't see it.

Comment: There's not much to see. If $t>2/n$ then $u_n(t)\ne 0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, How can you tell that? Could you please review the definition of $G$ and $u$?

Comment: Erm, _you_ should review the definitions in your post! I believe you're thinking about what you meant, while all I can go on is what you wrote; I doubt the two are the same. The is no definition of $u$ in your post. You say you want to show a function has compact support. You say the function is $u_n$. You define $u_n$ in terms of $G$, and it's _clear_ that $u_n$ does not have compact support, since $G$ does not have compact support, and $u_n$ is just a dilate of $G$.

Comment: There is no concrete definition of $u$, only the information I provided. $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$ and $u=0$ on $\partial(I)$. My bad, I forgot to specify this, excuse me.

Comment: Look. You need to rewrite the thing so it makes sense. I suspect from your comments that you want to show $u$ has compact support. But you _say_ you want to show $u_n$ has compact support. And then, if in fact you want to show $u$ has compact support and all you're given about $u$ is what you say, then everything about $G$ and $u_n$ is totally irrelevant. This simply makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, no, I want to show that $u_n$ has compact support. I am sure about it.

Comment: We're going around in circles. It is totally obvious that $u_n$ does not have compact support.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If $u$ is a bounded function (And it is so, because $u \in W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^{\infty}(I)$ ), then for a fixed $n$ the set of points where $u_n$ does not vanish is bounded. Do we agree on this?

Comment: Oops. I've been misreading the definition of $u_n$, sorry. Small font... I take it the domain of $u_n$ is supposed to be $I$? I suspect that you're not phrasing things exactly as the author does. If the problem were to show that $u_n$ has compact support then your questions about where this or that is used would make sense to me. So I suspect that the author is actually showing that $u_n\in X_c(I)$, for some space $X$. That is, I suspect the point is to show that the support of $u_n$ is a compact subset of $I$. To show _that_ one would argue as you say he does...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The author seeks to show that $u_n \in C_c(I)$. And yes, the domain of $u_n$ is $I$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What I need to know is where exactly it is used that $u$ banishes on $\partial(I)$

Comment: Say $I=(0,1)$. If $u$ did not vanish on the boundary of $I$ it could happen that the support of $u_n$ was $[0,1]$, in which case $u_n\notin C_c(I)$.

Comment: You are right, that solved the question. I was mistakenly assuming that $supp(u_n)$ was a subset of $I$, which is not true, as we are taking the closure. Thank you very much for your time.